# Drop down list selection Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, drop-down-menu

I want to populate a cell depending upon the drop down selection. How can i do it? The drop down list is created manually in the sheet.

EDIT: I have a column where every cell is a drop-drown. Depending upon what i select in the drop-down, the adjacent cell should get populated with a value.

Comment: This is awfully unclear. Please show us what you already have and what want to have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets say you have a dropdown box in A1 allowing values 1,2, or 3, and you want B1 to show "A", "B", or "C" accordingly. Just type the formula

```
=IF(A1=1,"A",IF(A1=2,"B",IF(A1=3,"C","-")))
```

into B1. Of course, this works also when you have no dropdown box in A1.

Comment: What if all the cells in a column are drop-downs? How can i modify the formula accordingly?

Comment: @Abhi If every cell you wish to populate is directly adjacent to the drop down, couldn't you just paste the formula down?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on Vlookup and Index Match they are usually easier to create and mantain than nested If . 
If you need examples let me know